# How can I install a .bin file?

Tags: software-installation

I want to update Acrobat Reader for Firefox, but the download has the `.bin` extension. How can I install it?

Comment: You should always try to install software from repositories (that is using synaptic/software center) to get security updates, new release,etc much more easily. Please note that you won't get support (from launchpad.net, ubuntuforums.org or other Ubuntu support channels) for applications that aren't installed from official sources.

Answer (score 183):

Go into a terminal and issue the following command in the directory where the bin file is,

```
chmod a+x name_of_file.bin
```

Then run it by writing

```
./name_of_file.bin
```

If you get a permission error and/or you're dealing with an installer that applies system-wide changes you might have to launch your application with root privileges:

```
 sudo ./name_of_file.bin
```

Comment: Hi, I am very illiterate in terminal. I have the bin file in desktop. Please tell me how to execute it. thanks

Comment: In terminal type **cd Desktop** and press enter.And then type **chmod a+x name_of_file.bin** and press enter.Finally type **sudo ./name_of_file.bin** It will install the bin file.

Comment: if you wanted to do this without the terminal you can flip executable bit with right click properties -> permissions -> set executable bit.  but run as I don't know how to do without a terminal

Comment: @aking1012 - just double click an executable file :)

Comment: @rafalcieslak that doesn't get you sudo

Comment: @aking1012 Alt+F2 and `gksudo`?

Comment: You don't have to use `sudo` all the time, if the .bin file doesn't require it.

Comment: Works fine ob Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Just a heads up on Debian 10 Buster (from Chrome os ) I got a warning that I needed to install VirtualBox

Answer (score 21):

Right click and select properties then go to permissions tab and tick allow excecuting.

[image]

Now double click the file and select run.

Some binaries require to be run from a terminal. If that's the case with your `.bin` file and/or nothing happens after double-clicking, drag the file into a new terminal window and run it by pressing 'Return'. The output should give you a clue on what's wrong.

Comment: So!
1. I changed the "allow exectuing " from properties.
2. used chmod to change permission, currently the permission is -rwxr-xr-x-
3. then i executed using .?filename.bin
there is no response after that! what should i do?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to globally install any binary, use the `install` command.

```
sudo install ./mybin /usr/bin/
```

The `install` command is used to copy files, and it does so by combining several commands into one to make them easy to use, i.e. `cp`, `chown`, `chmod`, and `strip`.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to update the Acrobat reader for firefox.

Adobe Reader is available in the [Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/acroread).

Answer (score 2):

**Important note:** This is only relevant for packages that don't have a 64-bit version (e.g. Acrobat Reader). Installing ia32-libs is not required if you can download a 64-bit executable and/or are running a 32-bit system  in the first place.

---

If your 64-bit Ubuntu doesn't have the following package installed , you will not able to access Acrobat Reader.

Follow the steps below:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
chmod a+x yourfile.bin
sudo ./yourfile.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

change permission of your file to executable by using terminal

copy your .bin or .run file to any location and then open terminal

In terminal type `ls` and it will show all files in that directory then change permission by root as show below

```
sudo su

chmod a+x filename.bin
```

then

```
./filename.bin
```

in this way you can run bin or run files in your ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

solution that works for me:

```
sudo bash xxx.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to location of file

like
if your file is your downloads then open terminal and follow below steps

```
acer@acer-TravelMate-P243:~$cd ~
acer@acer-TravelMate-P243:~$cd /home/user/Downloads
```

then change the persmissions of the .bin file to execute by terminal

```
acer@acer-TravelMate-P243:~$chmod a+x ./filename.bin -R
```

now you can run that file through  terminal

```
acer@acer-TravelMate-P243:~$./filename.bin
```