# How can I update my NVIDIA driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video

I recently installed the opensource game 0AD. Everything went fine, but when I run it I get the error

"You are using 260.19.* series NVIDIA drivers, which may crash the game. Please upgrade to 260.19.21 or later."

How do I go about updating this driver? I downloaded the 260.19.21 driver [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-260.19.21-driver.html).
Its a .bin file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Newer NVIDIA drivers are available in the X Updates PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

You want to add `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` to your software sources to upgrade them, you can follow these instructions here:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: +1 I preffer this way, because with this ppa you will get the latest drivers when they come out. :)

Comment: Hmmm. I added this and went to the repository but I couldn't find the NVIDIA driver I was looking for. Nothing for the NVIDIA driver I mentioned above.

Comment: 270.41.19 is in there, can you edit your question and tag it with the version of ubuntu you're using?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install the binary that comes directly from Nvidia, I can tell you how I have accomplished this in the past.

1. Switch to TTY `CTRL-ALT-F1`
2. Find the PID for **gdm-binary** (e.g., `ps ax | grep 'gdm-binary'`)
3. Kill associated PID for **gdm-binary** (e.g., `sudo kill -9 1136`)

[image]

With X shutdown, you are ready to install the binary from Nvidia.  Please use the appropriate name for the binary you are attempting to install.  The following example is using the NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-270.41.19.run binary downloaded from Nvidia:

```
`sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-270.41.19.run`
```

Now it is a matter of following the prompts presented when running the binary.  Generally speaking, I do not allow the binary to monkey with my xorg.conf.  Once the Nvidia driver has been installed, I tend to like to shutdown the system rather than to reboot.

`halt` or `shutdown now`

Upon booting the system, if all has to gone to plan, the new Nvidia driver should functional.  Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to kill gdm, `sudo stop gdm` will just stop the service.

Comment: I tried this attempt because the above answer didn't have an option for the driver in question (260.19.21+). Unfortunately, it didn't turn out very well and I ended up having to sh ./NVIDIA... --uninstall and uninstall the driver and revert back. Thanks tho. I doubt it was your instructions that caused problems.

Answer (score -1):

This tells you how to install a bin file:

- [How can I install a .bin file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-install-a-bin-file)