# Installing/executing .bin file

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install a .bin file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-install-a-bin-file)

I have a `.bin` file called `file.bin` and I am new to ubuntu and I am trying to figure out how to install it.

What is the proper command to run via Terminal?

I have tried:

```
./file.bin - reports error "Directory does not exist"
```

and

```
sudo ./file.bin - nothing happens at all with this command.
```

How do I execute this binary?

Comment: Make sure you are in the same directory as the file, when you type "ls", does "file.bin" show up?

Comment: It's not called "file", it's called "file.bin"; the suffix is part of the file name.  Where did you get it?  It's likely that `./file.bin` is the correct way to install it, but a file whose name ends in `.bin` could be anything.

Comment: Yes it does. http://screensnapr.com/v/JJ4bZA.png

Comment: Given the screenshot, I would guess that install.sh is the file you want to run, not file.bin.

Comment: It was probably complaining that it couldn't execute the command named on the `#!` line at the top of `file.bin`.  But from the looks of your screen snapshot, I suspect you should be running `install.sh`, not `file.bin` (`install.sh` probably takes care of invoking `file.bin` in the appropriate manner).  What did the installation instructions tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the directory where you have your file (say `file.bin`) and ensure the permissions will allow you to run it:

```
chmod u+x file.bin
```

Then run it with either of:

```
./file.bin
sudo ./file.bin
```

You may alternatively have to use something like:

```
bash file.bin
```

You should refer to the installation instructions. If they're good, they will tell you *exactly* what you should do. If not, I'd be circumspect about the software since the developers aren't as good as they think they are :-)

Comment: http://screensnapr.com/v/lw1add.png Still comes up with the same

Comment: I have followed the instructions, and when i use bash command it says "Cannot execute binary file" and the software is hldsupdatetool from valve software.

Comment: Don't worry problem solved, was missing lib32gcc1.