# How can I fix these Pango and fontconfig errors while trying to run Promethease?

Tags: 14.04, fonts, pango

I am trying to install the DNA-Analyzer [Promethease](http://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Promethease) but I am running into a few issues. After following the advice in [How can I install a .bin file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-install-a-bin-file) I got the Promethease executable to run but it looks like the GUI is corrupted. Instead of characters I only see squares.

This is the corresponding output when running Promethease from a terminal:

```
nuc@nuc:~/Downloads$ sudo ./promethease
python version 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:13:52) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
using 64bit
using frozen  /tmp/_MEIgwdF7c
temp is /tmp/tmpAFAjuq
I am: 0
terminal_interface loaded
can't use mwparserfromhell
argv ['/home/nuc/Downloads/promethease']
ui is starting wizard
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
UI logging to /home/nuc/Downloads/promethease.log
CWD:  /home/nuc/Downloads
Redirecting logging to /home/nuc/Downloads/promethease.log

(promethease:14629): Pango-CRITICAL **: No modules found:
No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.
PangoFc will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of:
  '/etc/pango/pango.modules'
You should create this file by running:
  pango-querymodules > '/etc/pango/pango.modules'

(promethease:14629): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'

(promethease:14629): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'
CWD:  /home/nuc/Downloads
logged to /home/nuc/Downloads/promethease.log
user interface completed with status=0
```

How can I fix these issues and get Promethease to work properly?

Comment: @roadmr The given answer there doesn't work. Please try it.

Comment: @Jan As I've written clearly in the title, I want to install the software, nothing broad about that.

Comment: @empedokles In what way doesn't it work? What happens when you run the `.bin` file after making it executable? Do you get an error message? If not, try running it from the terminal (drag and drop bin file onto terminal so the path appears in the prompt, then hit Return). Do you get an error message now?

Comment: @Glutanimate I posted the error I receive above. A GUI opens too, but there are all squares displayed instead of characters. Did you try the file in question? Also, it doesn't seem to have a .bin ending.

Comment: @empedokles The file extension isn't important on Linux systems. `.bin` is just somewhat of a convention for executable binary files. For what it's worth, I've given it a try and Promethease looks to be running fine on my system. No idea where these errors stem from but I have edited your question according to the new information and nominated it for reopening.