# How do I install Accelrys DS Visualizer on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I downloaded the .bin file format Accelrys DS Visualizer (if you want to download the file yourself you have to go through a process of filling out a form on their website, the starting point for this process is here http://accelrys.com/products/discovery-studio/visualization-download.php) that is designed to be able to be installed on Linux operating systems like Ubuntu and I carried out the instructions in the answer to this question [How can I install a .bin file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-install-a-bin-file) by karthick87 (including going through the installer) and I then clicked the desktop icon on my desktop and nothing happened.

Comment: this is a java dependent program. So go get iced tea or something. But after that, youll find the precompiled binary checks your OS version, and wont run in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following link would not help you:

https://extras.csc.fi/biosciences/DS/share/htmldoc/Install/DSVisualizer/inst_linux_install.html

I will try and report back.
Gert Kruger